# How do i run some python code in the background

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, background, scheduled-tasks

So I'm making a website using Django, and there is some code that I have set up to run every hour, however when I call this as a function in views.py it doesn't load the web page until the function has finished which isn't ideal for my website, I want it to be a background process which occurs outside my views file.

Answer (score 1):

A traditional approach if you use some UNIX-like system is writing a management command doing what you like to do, and running that management command (with `./manage.py <your_custom_command>`) from cron.

Run it from some account that has access to the source code and relevant database tables. Don't run it as root. If you use python virtualenv for your site, you should activate it before running *manage.py*.

You could for example run `crontab -e` as that user, and add an entry like

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
# run your comand on every hour, minute 00
0 * * * *  bash -c '. /your-site/env/bin/activate;/your-site/manage.py your_custom_command'
```

Custom management commands:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: No, not specifically. You could run Django on a Pi, but I would recommend that only for something that you use only in your home - perhaps for example some home automation system.

Otherwise, you can run cron (or similar tools) on almost all places where you can run Django. Probably some web hosting site or such.

If you make your own installation on a Pi facing the global internet, be a bit extra careful about what you need for security.

Answer (score 0):

A common tool to handle longer running jobs is celery: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: Adding to this, Celery has special Django integrations with `django_celery_results`. Data can be directly uploaded to your database through the ORM